# Get info about running process ssh

Tags: ssh, process

How can get more info about the process that is running?
I want to know what the process is doing and why it is using that much CPU.

How can I get this info using SSH?

Comment: read into [ps](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) (or if you want a more GUI-style overview of processes: [top](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top) or [htop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop)) but generally speaking, over ssh you can execute whatever your target machine (usually a *nix server) supports and gives your user access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH in and then use the **ps** command to list running processes in conjunction with the **grep** command to filter that result list down to what you need:

So for example if you wanted to find the **httpd** process you could use

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

**ps** will list all the process and **grep** will filter out the result list.